# Determining resistance per load with only power and volts

Tags: power, voltage, current, resistance

I have a extra credit problem in my class and I'm slightly stumped as to where to go next after I determine the It, Et and Rt.  I am starting with a total power of 2 watts and 32 volts.  I know to get current it is P/E= I which is 62.5 mA.  Then to get Rt, I would do E/I= R which is 32/62.5mA = 512.

That is as far as I have gotten.  There are three resistors with unknown resistance and unknown voltage.  The last info I have is R1= 5*R3 and R2= 2*R3.  That's all the info I have.  Maybe I am over thinking something but I am not sure where to go to solve this.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have a schematic?

Comment: I do on the sheet that was handed out.  its a straight line with 34 volts at the top.  then goes straight down to give three resistor symbols.

Comment: so series and 32 not 34

Comment: Christ.  i just messed that all up. yea its 32.

Answer (score 1):

***I am assuming the resistors are all in series. A schematic would be helpful.***

This is just algebra.

The total resistance is the sum of all three resistors:

\$R_t = R_1 + R_2 + R_3\$

And we have substitution values for \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$:

\$R_1 = 5R_3\$

\$R_2 = 2R_3\$

And since we know the total resistance, we can rearrange the equation to help us determine what \$R_3\$ is:

\$512 = 5R_3 + 2R_3 + R_3\$

or:

\$512 = 8R_3\$

\$\frac{512}{8} = 64\$

Thus:

\$R_1 = 320\$, \$R_2 = 128\$, and \$R_3 = 64\$

With that, I'll leave you to calculate the voltage on each resistor using \$E = IR\$.

Comment: I bet they're in parallel LOL

Comment: The OP originally used the "series" tag, which is what I'm going off. :)